# How to load ArrayList data into ListView using Android?

Tags: java, android, json, listview, arraylist

I am trying to create `JSON data store` into `ArrayList` and load on `ListView`. Now I have successfully stored my `JSON data` into `ArrayList`. But the problem is I have maintaining `multiple column` `listview`. I need to List out my first array on first column.

Below I have tried something, multiple columns with array. But exactly I dont know how to do that. Please help me, I am new developer for Android.

```
// I need to add my array into first column 
private ArrayList<String> myarray = new ArrayList<String>();

//JSON string data's I have loaded
myarray.add(jsondata);

//LISTVIEW WATCHLIST
ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "Minchu");
temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "USA");
temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "City");
temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "Ranks");
list.add(temp);
.
.
.
.
ListViewAdapters adapter=new ListViewAdapters(this,list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`NOTE :` Above `HashMap` to putted manual data. `I need to load first array first columns`, second array second columns.

Comment: have gone through adapter doc? what you need is a custom adapter, not a string adapter. create a custom adapter for your listview.

Comment: Make a custom adapter and getter setter for showing the data at what place you want too.

Comment: Please give me immidiate solution. I will learn str. want to get that outputs!Please post some samples

Answer (score 0):

You need to create model for your json object see below code.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class PersonDetailsItem implements Serializable {
public int id;
private String intEducationEN, intVillageID;

public PersonDetailsItem(int id, String name, String phoneNo, String email) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.id = id;
    this.strNameEN = name;
    this.strEmailid = email;
}

public String getIntVillageID() {
    return intVillageID;
}

public void setIntVillageID(String intVillageID) {
    this.intVillageID = intVillageID;
}

public String getIntEducationEN() {
    return intEducationEN;
}

public void setIntEducationEN(String intEducationEN) {
    this.intEducationEN = intEducationEN;
}

public PersonDetailsItem() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

Then set the value for the model form parsing json received string.

```
  private void parseJson(String rs) {
  private ArrayList<PersonDetailsItem> listData = new      ArrayList<PersonDetailsItem>();;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listData = new ArrayList<PersonDetailsItem>();
        spinerPersonData = new ArrayList<SpinerItem>();
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(rs);

            JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("Table");
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = jArray.optJSONObject(i);
                String intEducationEN = c.getString("intEducationEN");
                String intVillageID = c.getString("intVillageID");

                PersonDetailsItem personItem = new PersonDetailsItem();

                personItem.setIntEducationEN(intEducationEN);

                personItem.setIntVillageID(intVillageID);

                listData.add(personItem);


            }

        } catch (JSONException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("perosnJson Error", e.toString());

        }
    }
```

set to listadapter

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.id.listView1, listData);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
enter code here
```

You can check link for more detail https://github.com/yagneshshinde101/mysamaj/blob/master/MySamaj/src/com/example/mysamajmain/MainActivity.java

Comment: Its hard to understand for me! Do u have any other simple solution!

Comment: just create simple class with setter and getter and parse json with setdata.